# DBContext Query returns null

Tags: asp.net-core

Codes inside `Weekly` returns a value. But in `Monthly` it returns null.

I tried to run the query in my SQL Server Management Studio and it returns the correct result. But in my code, it returns null.
I tried to breakpoint and the `item.JobId` is = 2.

Here is my codes.

```
if (item.Frequency == "Weekly")
                    {
                        if (item.StartDate.DayOfWeek.ToString() == DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString())
                        {
                            var jobname = _context.Jobs.Where(x => x.Id == item.JobId).FirstOrDefault();
                            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                            {
                                jobs.Id = 0;
                                jobs.Job = jobname.Job;
                                jobs.ClientName = jobname.ClientName;
                                jobs.ClientId = jobname.ClientId;
                                jobs.JobRate = jobname.JobRate;
                                jobs.Status = "Active";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (item.Frequency == "Monthly")
                    {
                        if (item.StartDate.Day.ToString() == DateTime.Now.Day.ToString())
                        {
                            var jobname = _context.Jobs.Where(x => x.Id == item.JobId).FirstOrDefault();
                            var a =   jobname.Job;
                            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                            {
                                jobs.Id = 0;
                                jobs.Job = jobname.Job;
                                jobs.ClientName = jobname.ClientName;
                                jobs.ClientId = jobname.ClientId;
                                jobs.JobRate = jobname.JobRate;
                                jobs.Status = "Active";
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

And here is my SQL Query

```
SELECT        TOP (200) Id, Job, ClientName, ClientId, JobRate, Status
FROM            Jobs
WHERE        (Id = 2)
```

It should return some value in it.

Comment: It's hard to say. Can you share your code on github ?

Answer (score 0):

Both inner expressions of the ifs(ones controlling item.StartDate) are identical, so your problem lies in these controls. Can you make sure your code evaluates true for below condition?

```
if (item.StartDate.Day.ToString() == DateTime.Now.Day.ToString())
```